# Exponentials in the category of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma

Let $\Gamma$ be the category $e\overset{s}{\underset{t}{\rightrightarrows}}v$ and $\mathbf{Graphs}=\mathbf{Sets}^{\Gamma}$ the category of (directed multi) graphs.

For graphs $G$ and $H$, it's my understanding that the exponential object $H^G$ is the graph whose vertices are arbitrary functions $\varphi:G_v\to H_v$ and whose edges $\theta:\varphi\to\psi$ are functions $\theta:G_e\to H_e$ making these diagrams commute:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G_v @<s<< G_e @>t>> G_v\\
@V \varphi VV @VV \theta V @VV \psi V\tag{1}\\
H_v @<<s< H_e @>>t> H_v
\end{CD}

The evaluation homomorphism $\epsilon:H^G\times G\to H$ is defined on vertices by $(\varphi,v)\mapsto\varphi(v)$ and on edges by $(\theta,e)\mapsto\theta(e)$. For a homomorphism $f:F\times G\to H$, the transpose homomorphism $\lambda f:F\to H^G$ is defined on vertices by $v\mapsto f(v,-)$ and on edges by $e\mapsto f(e,-)$.

I'm trying to see how this falls out of the general construction of exponentials in categories of sheaves using the Yoneda lemma, but can't quite get things to line up.

Let $y:\Gamma^{\mathrm{op}}\to\mathbf{Graphs}$ be the (contravariant) Yoneda embedding. Then I believe:

- $y(v)$ is the "vertex graph" $\bullet$ consisting of a single vertex with no edges
- $y(e)$ is the "edge graph" $\bullet\to\bullet$ consisting of two vertices with one edge between them
- The graph $\bullet\times G$ is the graph of "vertices of G"
- The graph $(\bullet\to\bullet)\times G$ is the graph of "edges of G" consisting of (i) two copies $v_s$ and $v_t$ of each vertex $v$ of $G$ ($v_s$ represents "$v$ as a potential source" and $v_t$ represents "$v$ as a potential target"), and (ii) an edge $s(e)_s\to t(e)_t$ for each edge $e$ of $G$.

Now if $H^G$ is an exponential graph we must have

$$\begin{align*}
(H^G)_v&\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Graphs}}(y(v),H^G)\\
&\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Graphs}}(\bullet\ ,H^G)\\
&\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Graphs}}(\bullet\times G,H)\\
&\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sets}}(G_v,H_v)
\end{align*}$$

which checks out, and

$$\begin{align*}
(H^G)_e&\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Graphs}}(y(e),H^G)\\
&\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Graphs}}(\bullet\to\bullet,H^G)\\
&\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Graphs}}((\bullet\to\bullet)\times G,H)
\end{align*}$$

However, in general won't there be more graph homomorphisms from $(\bullet\to\bullet)\times G$ to $H$ than functions $\theta:G_e\to H_e$ satisfying (1), for example if $G$ has isolated vertices?

My understanding is that a graph homomorphism is a mapping of vertices to vertices and edges to edges which respects sources and targets of edges, so for an isolated vertex $v$ in $G$ we could map the isolated vertices $v_s$ and $v_t$ of $(\bullet\to\bullet)\times G$ freely for any given mapping of edges.

What is my error?

Comment: Can you clarify why you think there would be a mismatch between the number of graph homomorphisms $y(e)\times G\to H$ and the other notion above?

Comment: If one of your vertices $G_v\to H_v$ hits an isolated vertex in $H$, then it's an isolated vertex in $H^G$ under both descriptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven’t specified what exactly you think $\bullet\to\bullet \times G$ is, so lets do so: it’s the graph with vertices $G_v\times \{0\}\cup G_v\times \{1\}$ and edges $(x,0)\to (y,1)$ for every edge $x\to y$ in $G$. A map from this to $H$ precisely consists of functions $f_0,f_1:G_v\to H_v$ and $f:G_e\to H_e$ such that $s\circ f=f_0\circ s$ and $t\circ f=f_1\circ t$, as you say.

It is true that $f_0$ and $f_1$ are unconstrained in their action on isolated vertices by $f$, as you also say. Your initial description implies that $f_0$ and $f_1$ should be determined by $f$, and indeed in general they are not. An edge of the exponential graph is the whole triple.

Comment: Why is there an edge $(x,0)\to(x,1)$ for every vertex $x$ in $G$? I thought there would just be an edge $(s(e),0)\to(t(e),1)$ for every edge $e$ in $G$. I edited my question to reflect my understanding of the edge graph and graph homomorphisms.

Comment: @blargoner Oh, hang on...Gosh, non-reflexive graphs are awful.

Comment: @blargoner OK, I’ve edited. I now agree with everything you say. Whoever told you the overly simple description was perhaps not thinking carefully enough about how annoying non-reflexive graphs are, or there may have just been a miscommunication about giving the whole triple rather than just the edge map.

Comment: Ah, of course, an edge must be the whole triple, otherwise the source and target are not uniquely determined! I wasn't paying enough attention to that when considering the simple description. Thanks!